# I need to import data from .txt to SQL

Tags: sql, import, text-files

I have a text file that I need to import into a database, possibly using SQL to do so. I am simply trying to get the addresses into a table in the following format:

Address City, State, Zip.

The following is an altered example of the text I am trying to use:

```
DOE, JANE
     id:0123456465       alt id:246465  165165  department:TEST    

*Address Information--  Mailing Address:1

      address1:
          City, State:TEST CITY, STATE
                Line1:14566 Test Avenue
                  Zip:12345
      address2:
  none

      address3:
  none
```

I only need the info in address 1, but there are 40,000 entries. Does anyone have any ways that I could get this done efficiently?

Comment: Does the RDBMS you have in mind have bulk loading utility?

Comment: 1.) Are these entries in one big file? 2.) Do you have access to a scripting language like python or awk (if you use Linux, then you have.)

Comment: @tzunghaor Yes, it is in one large file, and I do have access to python

Answer (score 0):

as an example of a python implementation,

```
import re
idPat = re.compile("id:(\d+)")
cityPat = re.compile("City, State:(.*)")
zipPat = re.compile("Zip:(\d{5})")
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read().split('\n') # or split('\r\n') in windows

ID = CITY_STATE = ZIP = None

# assuming you have all of the data in an array, with each element being a line
foreach line in data: 
    if ID is None:
        m = idPat.search(line)
        if m is not None:
            ID = m.group(0)
            CITY_STATE = ZIP = None
    else:
        if CITY_STATE is None:
            m = cityPat.search(line)
            if m is not None:
                CITY_STATE = m.group(0)
                ZIP = None
        elif ZIP is None:
            m = zipPat.search(line)
            if m is not None:
                ZIP = m.group(0)
                print "UPDATE `table` SET `CityState`='%s', `Zip`='%s' WHERE `id`='%';"%(CITY_STATE, ZIP, ID)
                ID = CITY_STATE = ZIP = None
```

this will just print out a bunch of sql statements. you might be able to just bulk-import that into your phpmyadmin (for example) console. or python has bindings to connect to many database types.

Answer (score 0):

If the scructure is always this strict, and values have only ASCII characters then something like this makes an sql file

```py
fin = open('janedoe.txt', 'r')
fout = open('janedoe.sql', 'w')

inAddress1 = 0
address = {}
dataNo = 0 # just want to see how much is processed
for line in fin:
    line = line.strip()
    if inAddress1:
        if line == 'address2:':
            fout.write( "insert into Address (CityState, Line1, Zip) " + 
                "values ('%s', '%s', '%s');\n" % 
                (address['CityState'], address['Line1'], address['Zip']))
            inAddress1 = 0
        else:
            key, value = line.split(':', 1)
            key = key.translate(None, ', ')
            value = value.replace("'", "''") # sql escape string
            address[key] = value
    elif line == 'address1:':
        dataNo += 1
        if 0 == dataNo % 100:
            print dataNo

        inAddress1 = 1
        address = {}

fin.close()
fout.close()
```